# Codeception an Laravel Login/Auth not working

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, codeception

I am struggling with loging in a user via codeception and Laravel 5.
Whenever I try to login the user and navigate to a page, codeception is redirected to my /login page (=because the login seems to fail?!)

**How do I login the user?**

> 1) Failed to add new in ProjectCest::createPost
>   (tests/functional/ProjectCest.php)
>
> Step  I click "Add new"  Fail  Link or Button by name or CSS or XPath
>   element with 'Add new' was not found.

```
<?php

use App\User;

    class ProjectCest
    {

        public function clickAddNew(FunctionalTester $I)
        {
            $I->amLoggedAs(User::find(1));
            $I->amOnPage("/project");
            $I->click('Add new');
        }
    }
```

---

```
// functional.suite.yml
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled:
        # add framework module here
        - \Helper\Functional
        - Asserts
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost:9000'
```

Comment: Try navigate to the page "/project" from browser and it's open source code. In the source code try to find text "Add new". Does the text exist?